# Can't call function when clicking

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function blub()
{
    var x = $("#content").attr("data-x");
    $("#content").append(x);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <a href="" data-x="12" onClick="blub()">Link</a><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

leads to "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: blub"

What most likely obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: favourite question in SO `Can't call function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
function blub()
{
    var x = $("#content").attr("data-x");
    $("#content").append(x);
}
```

Instead of using :

```
$(function blub()
{
    var x = $("#content").attr("data-x");
    $("#content").append(x);
});
```

In your code you are calling a function(`callback`) without declaring it. this is not correct way to declaration a function.

[JavaScript Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp)

According your code you don't need to do any thing on `document ready` because your function trigger when anyone click on anchor `Link`. And the second thing is your code is not correct see this one  `$("#content").attr("data-x")` Here you trying to get the `data-x` attribute of `content` div, but your div does not contains that attribute use this `$("a").attr("data-x")`:

Try the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function blub() //-- It's declarition of an function 
{
    var x = $("a").attr("data-x");
    $("#content").append(x);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <a href="" data-x="12" onClick="blub()">Link</a><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Px4V4/1/)

Comment: I was trying to simplify the problem. From what I read, this is the short form for $( document ).ready (http://api.jquery.com/ready/). In the examples there they declared a function like that.

Comment: @Fabitosh I bet they don't use inline event handlers (`onclick="..."`). Defining a function inside document ready makes it local and the event handler can't find it.

Comment: @Fabitosh: If you write any code inside the "$(document ).ready(function(){});". means the code execute when the document is load. See this example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Px4V4/2/ , in example you can see the value of "data-x" attribute append when the document load is fully loaded. (So, if you want to append the value on $( document ).ready(function(){}) then no need to add onclick event of anchor).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function blub()
{
    var x = $("#content").attr("data-x");
    $("#content").append(x);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
    <a href="" data-x="12" onClick="blub()">Link</a><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you changed in the code and why?

Comment: if you define a local function you dont need to wrap it in `$(...)`

Answer (score 0):

The function blub is local to your script because your passed it as an argument to the jQuery object by wrapping your code with $(...);. Your function is executed when the DOM finishes loading, but in a local scope, which you cannot access from an event attribute. The best way to solve your problem would be not to use an event attribute. Moreover, the div #element doesn't have a "data-x" attribute. Its child a element has one. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bg38q/9/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#targetlink").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = $("#targetlink").attr("data-x");
        $("#targetlink").append(x);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting the error is because it can't find the value `.attr("data-x");` on the tag `<div id="content">`. It simply doesn't exist there. If you're looking to append the `data-x="12"` as a value inside the `<div>` tag, you could do something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content"> 
    <a href="#" data-role="appender" data-x="1234">Link</a>
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('a[data-role="appender"]').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var x = $(this).data('x');
                $('#content').append(x);
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

The code above attaches the code to the `.click` function in jQuery and is wired up using the `$('a[data-role="appender"]')` which makes your mark up a little bit cleaner. Hope this helps out ! The working solution can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrV8z/